# Why is this canvas not visible?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have made a simple canvas and I am begining to build a game. But when I only try to run the html script, it doesn`t work. I know I am not supposed to ask a question like this, WHY IS IT NOT WORKING?!?. But I am now so desperate that I hope you guys can help me

The main problem is that the canvas is not showing up, that means I think that there is a problem in my javascript..

Thnx so much!

```
<html>
    <head>

        <style>

Body {
    background-color: slategrey;
}
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">


function Canvas(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas').getContext('2d');
    var snelheid = 1;

    function background(){
        this.x = 0, this.y = 0, this.w = ctx.canvas.width, this.h = ctx.canvas.height, this.color = "yellow", this.count = 1;
        this.draw {
            ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
            //if(this.count>20){Canvas();}
        }
    }

    var background = new background();

    function draw() {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
        //draw

        background.draw();

        ctx.restore();
    }

    var animateInterval = setInterval(draw,1);
}

window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
    Canvas();
});
        </script>       

        <canvas id="my_canvas" width="450" height="600">
            De game werkt niet in je browser... Download een nieuwe browser!
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't you understand why you're supposed to tell what happens and what doesn't and whether there are errors in the console ?

Comment: Open console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`. This line `this.draw { ... }`. This is not how you define a function in javascript.

Comment: `this.draw {` ... You could have tried to isolate the problem instead of dumping the whole code to SO...

Comment: how do you see that dfsq??

Comment: @ThomasPereira F12 [read this!](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console)

Comment: I read it thnx for that! but what means it..?

Comment: oooh thnx guys I see the problem!

Comment: can I delete this question now??

Comment: @ThomasPereira - yes, you certainly may. :)